# icmp redirect how to check if it works

Tags: icmp

I have seen on the internet many tips to disable icmp redirects. What I would like to know is how to properly check on windows and linux if it actually works?

I have managed to spoof a fake icmp redirect packet with scapy on linux, i can see that the packet is coming out/in to the target machine with tcpdump, but nothing is happening. I think I have a proper physical setup, I tried with a gateway on same subnet, and with one that is not - many combinations lets say - it didnt work. When I check in linux route of the IP I want to redirect to another gateway, it stays on the default. There is suposed to be and adnotation that says that the gateway used from icmp is cached.

I tried method from here:
http://blog.packetheader.net/2010/06/better-spoofing-of-icmp-host-redirect.html

I

Comment: Have you made sure the destinations for your ICMP redirect packet actually honour those?

Comment: If you mean if tragets have icmp redirects enabled, than yes. Fresh install of rasppbery Pi debian and some old windows 7, nothing changed and redirects are enabled by default.